# How to pass certificate path with Postgres database url string for SSL connection

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

I am trying to secure connection to AWS RDS instance over SSL for my Spring boot application. I have looked upon several blogs and official [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html) and accordingly modified my connection string to contain certain parameter related to SSL connection.

I have my certificate placed inside a cert folder in resources. Below is how I have tried to pass the certificate path:

```
jdbc:postgresql://myamazondomain.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/db_name?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=/cert/rds-ca-cert_name.p12&password=my_passwrord
```

Also I have tried:

```
jdbc:postgresql://myamazondomain.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/db_name?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=/src/main/resources/cert/rds-ca-cert_name.p12&password=mypassword
```

However, when I try to connect to the RDS from my ECS container, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL root certificate file /cert/rds-ca-cert_name.p12.

at org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory.<init>(LibPQFactory.java:120)

at org.postgresql.core.SocketFactoryFactory.getSslSocketFactory(SocketFactoryFactory.java:61)

at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:33)

at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:435)

at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:94)

at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)

at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)

at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)

at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
```

Can someone suggest what is the error here. What is the correct way of passing the certificate stored in classpath to jdbc connection string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to use `SingleCertValidatingFactory` class to specify certificate file on classpath (or from file system, environment variables etc). This class has argument `sslfactoryarg` where we can add path to certificate file.

Your URL should look like:

`jdbc:postgresql://myamazondomain.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/db_name?sslmode=verify-full&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.SingleCertValidatingFactory&sslfactoryarg=classpath:cert/rds-ca-cert_name.p12`

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I'm using spring boot and every other answer says to use `sslrootcert=root.crt` and it will be picked up from the resources folder, but this in not correct! Using `SingleCertValidatingFactory` is the key! Hopefully my comment helps others find your solution faster.