# Referencing a file at resource folder in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath

I have a spring boot project and it has `client.pem` file at resource folder `/src/main/resource/client.pem`

I want to refer this file in application.properties and it works as below if I run my app in local

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://*.*.*.*:5432/postgres?ssl=true&sslmode=verify-ca&sslcert=src/main/resources/client.pem
```

The same is not working when the app is deployed in Google kubernetes engine(GKE). I also tried refering it as `classpath:client.pem` or `/client.pem` but no luck. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tried url-escaping / symbols?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62989084/12092416 address your problem?